# How to capture hair wisp structure from an image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-manipulation

I want to draw a cue from a specified point along its gradient direction to capture structure of hair wisp. Like Figure2. and Figure3. from an ACM paper, I linked here: [Single-View Hair Modeling for Portrait Manipulation](http://www.lvdiwang.com/publications/imagehair/2012%5fimagehair.pdf). Now I draw an orientation map by gradients, but the results look very chaotic. 
This is my code:

```
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argv, char* argc[])
{
    Mat image = imread("wavy.jpg", 0);
    if(!image.data)
        return -1;

    Mat sobelX1;
    Sobel(image, sobelX1, CV_8U, 1, 0, 3);
    //imshow("X direction", sobelX);

    Mat sobelY1;
    Sobel(image, sobelY1, CV_8U, 1, 0, 3);
    //imshow("Y direction", sobelY);

    Mat sobelX, sobelY;
    sobelX1.convertTo(sobelX, CV_32F, 1./255);
    sobelY1.convertTo(sobelY, CV_32F, 1./255);

    double l_max = -10;
    for (int y = 0; y < image.rows; y+=3)                                                           // First iteration, to compute the maximum l (longest flow)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.cols; x+=3)
        {
            double dx = sobelX.at<float>(y, x);                                                        // Gets X component of the flow
            double dy = sobelY.at<float>(y, x);                                                        // Gets Y component of the flow

            CvPoint p = cvPoint(y, x);

            double l = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);                                                             // This function sets a basic threshold for drawing on the image

            if(l>l_max) l_max = l;
        }
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < image.rows; y+=3)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.cols; x+=3)
    {
        double dx = sobelX.at<float>(y, x);                                                        // Gets X component of the flow
        double dy = sobelY.at<float>(y, x);                                                        // Gets Y component of the flow

        CvPoint p = cvPoint(x, y);

        double l = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);                                                             // This function sets a basic threshold for drawing on the image
        if (l > 0)
        {
            double spinSize = 5.0 * l/l_max;                                                        // Factor to normalise the size of the spin depending on the length of the arrow

            CvPoint p2 = cvPoint(p.x + (int)(dx), p.y + (int)(dy));
            line(image, p, p2, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1, CV_AA);

            double angle;                                                                           // Draws the spin of the arrow
            angle = atan2( (double) p.y - p2.y, (double) p.x - p2.x);

            p.x = (int) (p2.x + spinSize * cos(angle + 3.1416 / 4));
            p.y = (int) (p2.y + spinSize * sin(angle + 3.1416 / 4));
            line(image, p, p2, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1, CV_AA, 0 );
        }
    }
    }

    imshow("Orientation Map", image);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Can any one give me some hints?

Answer (score 0):

Your Sobels are the same while they supposed to have different code for x and y. 0, 1 and 1, 0.on top of that you loose resolution and sign by specifying cv8U as depth inSobel and only then converting to float. Also please provide input resolution and your outcome image.

Comment: Hi Vlad, thank you for reply. I want to provide the input and out images, but I don't have enough reputations to upload image. Because this is the first time I ask questions on stackflow. And you mean I should use CV_32F as depth in Sobel? I tried that, but the output didn't have much difference.

Comment: you should also vary codes for horizontal and vertical sobers as 0, 1 and 1,0. If you get two horizontal ones instead your angles will be messed up.